# 'import discord' not working in Python 3.5

Tags: python, discord.py

I try to `import discord` in python 3.5, but I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\discord\client.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .voice_client import VoiceClient
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 65, in <module>
    from .gateway import *
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\discord\gateway.py", line 31, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .protocol import *  # noqa
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\aiohttp\protocol.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
ImportError: cannot import name 'format_date_time'
```

I installed discord inside Python35-32\Scripts using `pip install discord`. Additionally, I installed `asyncio` using `pip install asyncio` in the same directory.

The error pops up in my command prompt, when I type in "python", wait for it to open, and then type "import discord". I'm saying that just to be clear that it's not a "I have a file named XXX.py which clashes with something from the discord library" type of error.

Comment: Could you try to do `import wsgiref.handlers` and then `print(wsgiref.handlers.__file__)` to see where that points to? You could check in that file if the referenced function actually exists or if there is something strange going on with imports. Doing `pip install --upgrade wsgiref` could also be helpful

Comment: @FlyingTeller `print(wsgiref.handlers.__file__)` points to C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py. `pip install --upgrade wsgiref` gives: 

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hrb_suoa\wsgiref\

Comment: Is there a `format_date_time` inside `C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py`? How did you install your python version?

Comment: @FlyingTeller The `wsgiref\handlers.py` file is empty. That must be the problem.
As for how I installed my python version, I assume I downloaded it off the website, but I honestly don't remember.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be a fresh installation here. But you could also try pasting the file content from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/wsgiref/handlers.py)

Comment: @FlyingTeller This was the solution. Thank you very much. If you want to, post it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments you have added and the line

```
    File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\aiohttp\protocol.py", line 11, in <module>
    from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
ImportError: cannot import name 'format_date_time'
```

The problem seems to be that `'format_date_time'` could not be imported from the built in library wsgiref. Turns out that the file `...\Python35-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py` was completely empty indicating that something corrupted your python installation.

Two possible solutions:

1. Reinstall your python completely which also has the benefit of solving other potential corruptions that you might not have noticed yet (Note that the underlying cause for this corruption remains unknown)
2. Go into the [Cython git](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/wsgiref/handlers.py) and copy the contents of the `handlers.py` into the local file. This is a very specific solution however and you should be aware that other parts of your python installation might also be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to `pip install discord.py` instead of `discord`?

Comment: If I go `pip install discord.py`, I get multiple "Requirement already satisfied" prints. Not sure if the fact that I initially did `pip install discord` could be causing problems now, though.

Comment: Maybe just try to uninstall discord and reinstall dircord.py... `discord` looks like it's not maintained (or really young) https://pypi.org/project/discord/ , maybe it is using `discord.py` as a dependency and by writing your `import` statement, Python does not know which file to import (the module from `discord.py` or the whole `discord` package) and that's why you're getting this error

Comment: Also I should add that if you're not already doing so, try using virtualenvironment (https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) or some similar alternative that should avoid messing with packages installed globally

Comment: @Yoiro take a close look at the error message. The actual error `ImportError: cannot import name 'format_date_time'` has nothing to do with `discord` itself, but is occuring in a built in library that happens to be imported by it. It is therefore highly unlikely that reinstalling `discord` will fix the underlying issue

Comment: @FlyingTeller nice call mate. I wanted to answer too quickly, my bad.